# Unable to access exposed k8s service on AWS on the internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, kubectl

I have an image called hello-node on my AWS ECR (described at bottom of post). If I run it locally and go to localhost:8080 I see "hello world."

On my node on AWS I run:

`kubectl run hello-node --image=xxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/hello-node:v1 --port=8080` (account number blocked out)

then:

`kubectl expose deployment hello-node --type="LoadBalancer"`

and if I run:

`kubectl describe service hello-node`

I see (info edited)

```
Name:           hello-node
Namespace:      default
Labels:         run=hello-node
Annotations:        <none>
Selector:       run=hello-node
Type:           LoadBalancer
IP:         xx.xx.xx.xx
LoadBalancer Ingress:   xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Port:           <unset> 8080/TCP
NodePort:       <unset> 32059/TCP
Endpoints:      xx.xx.xx.xx:8080
Session Affinity:   None
```

I am trying to access my hello-node service online. I want to go to some web address or IP address in my browser and see 'hello world.'

I have tried going to the above-listed IP, LoadBalancer Ingress, and Endpoints, but those sites do not load in my browser. ***How can I access this service on the internet?*** I will provide any more info if required.

NOTE: if I do `kubectl port-forward hello-node-621867969-ztxnr 8080` then I can access it on localhost:8080 on my machine, so something is working at least.

**hello-node service:**

[Source here under 'Create an app, package it in a container and publish to a Docker registry' section](http://christopher5106.github.io/continous/deployment/2016/05/02/deploy-instantly-from-your-host-to-AWS-EC2-and-Google-Cloud-with-kubernetes.html)

server.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var handleRequest = function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200);
  response.end("Hello World!");
}
var www = http.createServer(handleRequest);
www.listen(8080);
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6.9.2
EXPOSE 8080
COPY server.js .
CMD node server.js
```

run `docker build -t hello-node:v1 .`

run `docker tag hello-node:v1 AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.REGION.amazonaws.com/hello-node:v1`

run `docker push AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/hello-node:v1` (put in my account and region info, and I verified that it is uploaded to my ECR)

Then I ran the two `kubectl` commands I listed in the start of this post.

Answer (score 0):

I can access it through `<loadbalanceringress>:<port>`. I honestly can't remember if I had tried that or not (I tried a lot of address:Port combinations.